# How can I tell the displacement that a canoe experiences when two people walk exchanging sides?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics, classical-mechanics

The problem is as follows:

The figure from below shows two students whose masses are $m_1$ and $m_2$ ($m_1 < m_2$) are situated on both ends of a canoe situated in a lake with calm waters. Find the displacement that the canoe whose mass is $m_3$ experiences until the instant the students exchange their initial positions.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The alternatives given are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\left(\frac{m_2 - m_1}{m_1 + m_2 + m_3}\right)L\\
2.&\left(\frac{m_3 - m_1}{m_1 + m_2 + m_3}\right)L\\
3.&\left(\frac{m_3 - m_2}{m_1 + m_2 + m_3}\right)L\\
4.&\left(\frac{m_2}{m_1 + m_2 + m_3}\right)L\\
5.&\left(\frac{m_3}{m_1 + m_2 + m_3}\right)L\\
\end{array}$

I'm confused exactly what sort of equation or analysis I can attempt to do in order to solve this question.
I think that it is related with momentum and I can consider that when they exchange positions the momentum is preserved.

But I dont know exactly if should I say:

$p_1+p_2+p_3= p_{1f}+p_{2f}+p_{3f}$

Should this be the right way to do?. Can someone help me here please?.

Comment: Even in lack of knowledge of physical equations, only the first answer matches simmetry requirement (if you swap the students, replacement should be the same, but with a negative value).

Comment: The displacement of the canoe depends upon the sum of the three masses and the shape of the canoe.  It is independent of L and slightly changed by elevation and water density.

Comment: @WilliamElliot Center of gravity should be preserved. Observe a special case with zero masses of boat and one of students, displacement of a boat is exactly L, as the center of gravity is positioned where a weighted student is.

Comment: @z100 Perhaps can you offer a solution or some sort of, because I'm still stuck with this problem. :(

Comment: You have been posting a series of classic exercises in centre of mass topics, but apparently trying to solve them through conservation of momentum. While it is not impossible, using centre of mass instead of momentum provides a more elegant solution and I suggest you take this as a learning opportunity to try to understand more about centre of mass.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Thanks, my opinion is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Take the students and the boat to be one system. When the students swap their positions, all forces used are internal (assuming negligible resistance by water). There is no net external horizontal force, so the horizontal position of centre of mass of the system stays constant. Fix a stationary origin. Let the student with mass $m_1$ be $x_1$ units away, the one with mass $m_2$ be $x_2$ units away, and the the centre of mass of the boat of mass $m_3$ be $x_3$ units away from the origin. The abscissa of the centre of mass of the system is$$x=\frac{m_1x_1+m_2x_2+m_3x_3}{m_1+m_2+m_3}$$There is no change in the abscissa, in other words $\Delta x=0$.$$m_1\Delta x_1+m_2\Delta x_2+m_3\Delta x_3=0$$where $\Delta x_i$ denotes the displacement of $m_i$. Now, $m_1$ undergoes a displacement of $L$ to the right and $\Delta x_3$ to the right. $m_2$ undergoes a displacement of $L$ to the left and $\Delta x_3$ to the right. Thus$$\Delta x_1=\Delta x_3+L\\\Delta x_2=\Delta x_3-L$$Plug these into the earlier equation and solve to isolate $\Delta x_3$.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell You can think about this as conservation of momentum. Since there is no force from outside, the net force is zero, so $\Delta p=0$. Assume that it takes a time $\Delta t$ to swap positions, so just replace everywhere in the above answer $\Delta x$ with $\Delta x/\Delta t$, and you get a momentum equation